# SmtpClient : Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sendmail

Добрый день.

Я отправляю почту через SmtpClient и получаю такое сообщение (примерно 2 ошибки на 1000 сообщений):

> SmtpException: Failure sending mail ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable
>   to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост
>   принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. --->
>   Socket.SocketException:  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал
>   существующее подключение.

Отправляю почту таким образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, 25);

        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
        m.Body = i.ToString() + " (1)";

        client.Send(m); //Error here

        Console.WriteLine(">> " + i + " (1)");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errors++;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
    }

}
```

Ошибка возникает на методе Send, причем всегда на разном сообщении, и.е. может на 20ом и 700ом, возникнуть, в а следующем запуске - на 500ом и 800ом.
Может что-то с СМТП-сервером , который обрабатывает сообщения?
Он рукописный.

Спасибо.

Comment: Просто повторите операцию. Код из try выносите в метод, в catch вызываете его же. Для защиты от переполнения стека ограничьте рекурсивный вызов каким нибудь числом - не больше 3 попыток например.

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне важно понять, где происходит ошибка. Сам СМТП сервис писал я, и таких ошибок раньше небыло. Может ,я неправ где-то

Comment: Сетевое соединение не обязано завершиться успешно. Таймаут, потерянный пакет, кривой роут - что угодно могло случиться. Плюс, у вашего сервера может быть ограничено количество открытых соединений, он может отказаться принимать новые.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказалась в СМТП-сервере.
Соединение отпадало по таймауту, и в этом была ошибка!

```
 if (!_clientSocket.Connected && ((DateTime.Now - _start).TotalMilliseconds > _sessionIdleTimeOut))
                    {
//disconnect
                        break;
                    }
```

//где
_start -  дата/время подключения клиента
//_sessionIdleTimeOut - время жизни сесси

Answer (score 0):

1. Перенесите:

   ```
   var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, 25);
   ```

   до начала цикла `for`. А так получается Вы каждый раз по новой инициализируете класс.
2. Так же попробуйте поиграться со свойством (по умолчанию оно составляет 100 секунд): [SmtpClient.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. Поставьте небольшую задержку, например `Thread.Sleep(300);`, после выполнения каждой итерации цикла `for`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все эти меры не помогли. После добавления Thread.Sleep ошибок стало не 2 а 6, т.е. я вижу сложность в таймаутах сервера.